# String convertions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, html-entities, iso-8859-1

I'm kinda new on Ruby and I having some trouble working with string convertions. I have this input in UTF-8

```
"O João e o pé de feijão"
```

and I need a output like this

```
"O Jo&atilde;o e o p&eacute; de feij&atilde;o"
```

in ISO-8859-1.

I tried to use the encode method, but, although it did converted to ISO-8859-1,
the output was

```
"O Jo\xC3\xA3o e o p\xC3\xA9 de feij\xC3\xA3o\nEssa \xC3\xA9 uma est\xC3\xB3ria que fez parte da infncia das crian\xC3\xA7as nascidas nos anos 70 e\n80."
```

Comment: [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) and [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HTMLEntities](https://rubygems.org/gems/htmlentities) gem.

```
> gem install htmlentities
Fetching: htmlentities-4.3.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed htmlentities-4.3.4
Parsing documentation for htmlentities-4.3.4
Installing ri documentation for htmlentities-4.3.4
Done installing documentation for htmlentities after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Example:

```
require 'htmlentities'
HTMLEntities.new.encode("O João e o pé de feijão", :named)
#=> "O Jo&atilde;o e o p&eacute; de feij&atilde;o"
```